# Excel VBA - Output cell formula (list) based on input cells that range from x to y

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to accomplish the below in excel and believe I need to use VBA. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Excel input

```
Cell A1 = A2*B2*C2
A2 ranges from x to y
B2 ranges from x to y
C2 ranges from x to y
```

Excel Output

```
Original Inputs, Formula Calculation (vertical list)

A2 B2 C2 , A1
```

Comment: By A2 ranges from x to y, do you mean as a column or a row? Have you tried the macro recorder in excel to try to come up with some sort of code?

Comment: Thank for the reply. I believe as a column. If A2, B2, C2 range from 1 to 3...output would look like..

Row 1 - 1 1 1 , 1...... Row 2 - 1 1 2 , 2....Row 3 - 1 1 3 , 3 and ect

Each one of those would be in its own column

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code will help you:

```
Sub foo2()
Dim A2(), B2(), C2() As Variant 'Declare the variables as Variant arrays
Dim LastRowA, LastRowB, LastRowC As Long

LastRowA = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find the last row with data on column A
LastRowB = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'find the last row with data on column B
LastRowC = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row 'find the last row with data on column C

A2 = Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & LastRowA) 'take all values form A1 to the last row in that column into the A2 array
B2 = Sheet1.Range("B1:B" & LastRowB)
C2 = Sheet1.Range("C1:C" & LastRowC)

For x = LBound(A2) To UBound(A2) 'loop from the begining of the array until the end
    Sheet1.Cells(x, 6).Value = A2(x, 1) 'enter the values of A2 into the column F which is the number 6
    Sheet1.Cells(x, 7).Value = B2(x, 1) 'edit this values to "paste" the values wherever you wish
    Sheet1.Cells(x, 8).Value = C2(x, 1)
    Sheet1.Cells(x, 9).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*RC[-2]*RC[-1]" 'this will enter the formula in those cells
Next x
End Sub
```